# Why prefer Non-SRGB format for vulkan swapchain?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

in the Vulkan cube example, the method to pick the surface format is:

```
vk::SurfaceFormatKHR Demo::pick_surface_format(const std::vector<vk::SurfaceFormatKHR> &surface_formats) {
// Prefer non-SRGB formats...
for (const auto &surface_format : surface_formats) {
    const vk::Format format = surface_format.format;

    if (format == vk::Format::eR8G8B8A8Unorm || format == vk::Format::eB8G8R8A8Unorm ||
        format == vk::Format::eA2B10G10R10UnormPack32 || format == vk::Format::eA2R10G10B10UnormPack32 ||
        format == vk::Format::eR16G16B16A16Sfloat) {
        return surface_format;
    }
}

printf("Can't find our preferred formats... Falling back to first exposed format. Rendering may be incorrect.\n");

assert(surface_formats.size() >= 1);
return surface_formats[0];
```

}

why would we prefer the non-SRGB formats, isn't most screens expecting the SRGB format?

Comment: It's important to understand that code quality on most graphics stuff for beginners is... not good. Most code out there does not exhibit good practices in a variety of ways. So if you see some code in a tutorial, and it doesn't explain why its making certain choices, it's best to assume that it's just what that particular user decided to do and does not necessarily represent good practices.

Comment: It is almost a non-question. One simply prefers what one needs. Can we assume you are asking what the sRGB feature does?

Comment: ^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401081/vulkan-swapchain-format-unorm-vs-srgb or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241749/what-is-vulkan-color-space

Comment: the vulkan cube example is comes with the vulkan sdk, I'm not asking about the difference between the srgb and linear color space, my question is why prefer non-srgb format in the official example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is: You generally do *not* prefer non-sRGB formats for the swapchain images.
Your doubts are totally justified: The code in question arguably does not show a best practice approach. Consider *Figure 1*, which shows the fundamental conversion stages involved when capturing images, storing them in a a low dynamic range (LDR) format, and displaying it through a computer monitor.

[image: Gamma Correction]
*Figure 1:* Clearly, physical radiance is in linear space (leftmost stage).  When we capture an image, we often want to store it in an LDR format (e.g., 8 bit or even less per color channel) to best utilize storage space ("LDR image" stage). Whatever radiance is output by a monitor must be again in linear space, otherwise we would have distorted the color values (rightmost stage). Since most (all?) monitors only support LDR framebuffer formats, they apply gamma correction to the framebuffer color values, before they emit the corresponding radiance (monitor stage).

I.e., your monitor expects gamma space as input.
Therefore, the proper approach is to send an sRGB format to your monitor.

In fact, checking [gpuinfo.org](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listoptimaltilingformats.php) and sorting the list by `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` support, one can observe that sRGB formats are the most commonly supported formats. Here are the top four formats support-wise:

- `B8G8R8A8_SRGB`: 99.88%
- `A8B8G8R8_SRGB_PACK32`: 99.72%
- `R8G8B8A8_SRGB`: 99.48%
- `B8G8R8A8_UNORM`: 99.44%

So, I would say, default to an sRGB format!

P.S.: In case you are wondering why it makes sense to use an LDR image format, have a look at *Figure 2* for an explanation!

[image]
*Figure 2:* The top row shows evenly spaced bars w.r.t. physical light intensity. This means, the amount of emitted photons increases by the same amount between each neighboring bar. The bottom row shows evenly spaced bars w.r.t. perceived light intensity---the increase of physical light intensity corresponds to the gamma curve shown in *Figure 1*. In other words, we only have to add a few photons in darker regions for a big change in perceived light intensity. For brighter regions, we have to add a lot of photons for the same relative difference in perceived light intensity. Therefore, it makes sense to store images so that relatively more bits are allocated for the darker colors, and fewer bits for the brighter colors in order to use the available bits optimally w.r.t. the human visual system.

Comment: maybe I've been working in graphics too much because I perceive the top bar as linear.